# Tomcat MAX Thread VS sessions

Tags: performance, tomcat, configuration, monitoring, offloading

We are using `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` and I have a question as to what the max concurrent sessions Tomcat can handle?

As per my understanding http11.Http11NioProtocol Tomcat can handle 10000 connection with 200 Threads.

Looking below, can I consider my Tomcat will handle around 70000 Sessions at a time?

```xml
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               maxThreads="1500"
               clientAuth="false"
               SSLEnabled="false"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
               proxyPort="443"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
               sessionCacheSize="16384"
               sessionTimeout="120"
               proxyName="test.com"
               redirectPort="443" />
```

Comment: Sessions can long outlive connections. There is no necessary relationship.

Comment: So, can I consider 70k Max concurrent connection ? at time ..

Comment: I have no idea what your hardware can handle.